# Issue when upgrading Autofac with async tasks and owned instances

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have an issue with Autofac after upgrading from 4.9.2 to 5.2 in my ASP.NET MVC application.
I make use of `Func<Owned<T>>` factory pattern in the Controller because an Controller Action starts a Long running Task and will run longer than the request exists. In that Task I am resolving other instances.

This worked fine in Autofac 4.9.2. But after upgrading to Autofac 5.2 the parent Lifetime scope (AutofacWebRequest) gets disposed and it not possible to resolve instances within the owned instance anymore.

```
Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it (or one of its parent scopes) has already been disposed.
```

Is there something I can do to work around this or is there a best practice?

Controller Code:

```
private readonly Func<Owned<IBusinessLogic>> _businessLogicFactory;
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var businessLogic = _businessLogicFactory();

    var unitOfWorkFactory = _unitOfWorkFactory;
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // Sleep simulates that it may take some time until other instances are resolved
        using (businessLogic)
        {
            var task = businessLogic.Value.DoHardBusinessAsync();
            task.Wait();
        }
    });

    return View();
}
```

Business Logic Code (also using a factory):

```
public class BusinessLogic : IBusinessLogic
{
    private readonly Func<Owned<OtherBusinessLogic>> _otherBusinessLogicFactory;

    public BusinessLogic(Func<Owned<OtherBusinessLogic>> otherBusinessLogicFactory)
    {
        _otherBusinessLogicFactory = otherBusinessLogicFactory;
    }

    public async Task DoHardBusinessAsync()
    {
        using (var otherBusiness = _otherBusinessLogicFactory())
        {
            await otherBusiness.Value.DoHardBusinessAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am honestly surprised the code _used_ to work, if you are resolving a dependency after the web request has finished... You are 100% sure the code is unchanged between the two versions?

Comment: If this ever worked, it was because you were getting lucky in the race condition where the `Task.Run` would get going long enough to do the resolve before the web request ended. You need to either resolve the `businessLogic` before starting the task or use a different lifetime scope like in @natalia-muray answer. In general it's probably not good practice to start a background task like this out of a web request because you'll get into thread starvation anyway.

Comment: Yes it worked for older releases. It does not any longer work starting with v5.0: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/releases/tag/v5.0.0

For good reasons ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to create a new lifetime scope that is independent of the request scope to be used with your long running task like so

```
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // Sleep simulates that it may take some time until other instances are resolved
            using (businessLogic)
            {
               var task = businessLogic.Value.DoHardBusinessAsync();
               task.Wait();
            }
        }
    });
```

Look at this question for ideas on how to get a hold of the container
[Retrieving Autofac container to resolve services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216003/retrieving-autofac-container-to-resolve-services)

Comment: Should perhaps `scope` be used to resolve the `businessLogic`?

Comment: Autofac will use 'scope' to inject instances into your constructors, rather than the automatically created request scope that is disposed when the request is completed. You  can resolve the factory from 'scope' to make sure anything injected via constructor will not be cleaned up when request's scope is cleaned up.

Comment: @NataliaMurray So `_otherBusinessLogicFactory()` will be "resolved" from the new scope, even though `businessLogic` was resolved (and thus the constructor called) from the web request scope? My impression from https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html#resolve-components-from-lifetime-scopes was that you needed to call `scope.Resolve`, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks @NataliaMuray, this Looks like a quite good solution. Is there a best practice how to Access the container in the Controller Action?

Comment: Anything that is already resolved is already resolved and will be disposed with request scope. It would be better to resolve businessLogic from 'scope' like you said above

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216003/retrieving-autofac-container-to-resolve-services. The accepted answer there is by Travis Illig. Basically create a single instance provider that caches your container

Answer (score 2):

@NataliaMuray's approach is awesome - one *downside* of it is that it tends to encourage Service Locator style resolving rather than constructor injection. This can tend to "hide" dependencies, making it harder to identify the dependencies of a given class.

One potential solution is to introduce the notion of a dependency that is explicit that it wraps *another* dependency that you want to resolve outside the normal web request's lifetime scope.

The code might look something like:

```
public class AsyncRunner : IAsyncRunner
{
    public ExecutionResult TryExecute<TService>(Action<TService> toEvaluate, string @exceptionErrorMessage, int timeoutMilliseconds, string additionalErrorInformation = "")
    {
        try
        {
            var task = new Task(() =>
            {
                using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
                {
                    var service = scope.Resolve<TService>();
                    toEvaluate(service);
                }
            });

            task.ContinueWith(t => { /* logging here */, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted | TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously).SuppressExceptions();

            task.Start();
            var completedWithinTime = task.Wait(timeoutMilliseconds);
            return completedWithinTime ? ExecutionResult.Ok : ExecutionResult.TimedOut;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            /* logging here */
            return ExecutionResult.ThrewException;
        }
    }
}
```

*Register IAsyncRunner with Autofac as well.*

And then your dependency, instead of

```
private readonly Func<Owned<IBusinessLogic>> _businessLogicFactory;
```

would be

```
private readonly IAsyncRunner<IBusinessLogic>> _businessLogic;
```

And instead of:

```
var businessLogic = _businessLogicFactory();
var unitOfWorkFactory = _unitOfWorkFactory;
Task.Run(() =>
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // Sleep simulates that it may take some time until other instances are resolved
    using (businessLogic)
    {
        var task = businessLogic.Value.DoHardBusinessAsync();
        task.Wait();
    }
});
```

would be:

```
//var businessLogic = _businessLogicFactory();
var unitOfWorkFactory = _unitOfWorkFactory;
Task.Run(() =>
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // Sleep simulates that it may take some time until other instances are resolved

    _businessLogic.TryExecute(z => {
        var task = z.Value.DoHardBusinessAsync();
        task.Wait();
    });
});
```

The advantage of this style is that the property and constructor injection makes clear what the dependencies are, and how they are being used (i.e. the declaration makes clear that it will be resolved outside the context of the standard lifetime scope). Note you don't need to use `Owned` with my suggestion (disposal of the lifetime scope that is manually constructed will be sufficient). I have removed the use of `Func`, but you could use `Func` or `Lazy` if you really needed it alongside my suggestion.

Comment: Oh, sorry. For some reason I did make that mistake. Well then give the OP ideas, not write the code for them. And I prefer to give the simplest example, the implementor can add complexity as they desire. Unfortunately at some point one has to resort to using the container directly to create the scope, there is no getting away from that

Comment: `Unfortunately at some point one has to resort to using the container directly to create the scope, there is no getting away from that` @NataliaMuray That is true - the point of my approach is to show a way of doing that which is closer to constructor injection than service locator (i.e. clearer).

Comment: `Well then give the OP ideas, not write the code for them.` I didn't write the code for them. I adapted my existing solution (since this is a problem I have solved in the past).

Comment: :) I did not take it that way and I also was not trying to critisize your approach, more of justifying my own. And I do like your approach. I think it is closer to how Autofac is intended to be used. I upvoted your answer.