Autofac Access the IoC container in .NET MAUI
I wanted to configure Autofac for my .NET MAUI project which I was able to do, now the thing is I would like to access the IoC container so I can manually resolve dependencies if needed for setting up my navigation service and other such situations.
In my MauiProgram I have this:
builder.ConfigureContainer(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory(), RegisterServices);

And the registration:
private static void RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
   // I register my services here
}

Now how would I access the IContainer that I just built here, I have been trying to skim through documentation and it seems there is no direct way to do this.

So I decided to follow the answer by Travis, one of the developers at Autofac.
The first thing you need to do is create a custom AutofacServiceProvider, where you can get the builder as a static provider, with a method to RegisterServices
internal class ExtendedAutofacServiceProviderFactory : IServiceProviderFactory<ContainerBuilder>
{
    public ContainerBuilder CreateBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        MauiProgram.RegisterServices(builder);
        builder.Populate(services);
        return builder;
    }

    public IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(containerBuilder);
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();
        ContainerProvider.Container = container;
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    }
}

Add a method to RegisterServices, I added it in the MauiProgram
internal static void RegisterServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
   //Register your services here
}

You also need a ContainerProvider and then use it
using IContainer = Autofac.IContainer;

internal static class ContainerProvider
{
    internal static IContainer Container { get; set; }
}

Then you can use this and Resolve whatever you need an example:
ContainerProvider.Container.Resolve<IYourService>();


What about just injecting your IContainer to your Services? Like that:
public class MyService
{
    public IContainer Container { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var dependency = Container.Resolve<IDependency>();
    }
}

Or as an alternative inject the ILifetimeScope :
public class MyService
{
  private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

  public PaymentHandler(ILifetimeScope scope)
  {
    _scope = scope;
    
    using(var childScope = _scope.BeginLifetimeScope)
    { 
        // Resolve your dependency
    }
  }
}


Umm should I be doing this though, I would be adding my AutoFac container, into my native .NET Service container, So my injections would be dependent on another dependency??

I made another post. Please have a look. Not sure about your exact question.

What are your thoughts on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48242516/7462031

Yes, also a possible solution. Maybe using a own Service with an interface instead of a static class for unit testing purposes, but ok.

I have given you the bounty but i decided that going ahead with the solution by the contributor @Autofac makes more sense and is easier to manage as well thanks for all your help!

If you want to directly access your registered services in your MauiProgram.cs after registering, I'm not sure for autofac but with the standard Microsoft DI framework it would work like this:
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();

var host = builder.Build();
var service = host.Services.GetService<IMyService>();

service.GetCustomers();

await host.RunAsync();

So the answer would be: Access your services after you Build() the host.

I want to access the IContainer from Autofac, check this out but this is XF https://dev.to/petermilovcik/setup-autofac-in-xamarin-forms-363h

As I just said: Just do IContainer container = builder.Build(); Its also mentioned in your link.

builder.Build() is a .NET IContainer, I want an AutoFac IContainer...

This is what is stated in the autofac docs:
https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/index.html
They just recommend to use builder.Build(); and than use a lifetime scope (as mentioned in my first answer), because of disposing reasons which could lead to memory leaks.
